# Should `DiscreteLimit` work when the argument type is specified?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, core-language

Is it expected that `DiscreteLimit` fails to evaluate whenever the argument type is specified? E.g.,

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := 0
DiscreteLimit[f[x], x -> Infinity]  (* evaluated *)

Clear[f]
f[x_Integer] := 0
DiscreteLimit[f[x], x -> Infinity]  (* not evaluated *)

Clear[f]
f[x : (_Integer | _Real | Infinity)] := 0
DiscreteLimit[f[x], x -> Infinity]  (* not evaluated *)
```

**Edit:** MichaelE2's comment implies that the following should work, and it does.

```
Clear[f]
f[x : (_Integer | _Symbol)] := 0
DiscreteLimit[f[x], x -> Infinity]  (* evaluated *)
```

Comment: A symbolic solver like `DiscreteLimit` needs a symbolic argument.  With a pattern-protected definition of `f[x]`, all the solver sees is the literal expression `f[x]`, about which nothing can be said. It will not examine the definitions of `f[]` and select one for analysis. It uses what the expression `f[x]` evaluates to. `DiscreteLimit` does not make a numerical estimate of the limit; the argument `x` remains a `Symbol` and is never an `Integer`.